# Facebook Graph API pages/conversations/messages endpoint error (suddenly seems deprecated)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, deprecated, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I've been successfully pulling messages from my pages using the Facebook Graph API until today when I started getting an error:

```
GraphAPIError: (#12) This endpoint is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher
```

I double checked my permissions using the Graph API Explorer tool, and replicated the error there: [image: messages edge unaccessible]

I also double checked the [Conversation Facebook Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/conversation), and it says

```
GET graph.facebook.com/{id}?fields=messages{message}
```

should work to access the content of a specific conversation, however I keep getting the deprecation error any time I'm trying to access to messages field.

Any thoughts what could have broken since yesterday, or an alternative way to extract my page messages trough the Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Facebook bug that's being treated as high priority.
Hopefully they'll fix it soon.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/163782704230317/

[image]